# Non-Lollipop Material Flat Buttons

Tags: android, button, android-appcompat, material-design

I want to do [material style flat buttons](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons) for systems before Lollipop. I'm using Android 4.4.4 and my Play Store looks like the following:

[image: Play Store]

The buttons and icons are neatly arranged as in the APPS, GAMES, BOOKS.

The MORE button shows buttons a button without an icon.

So how do I do cute buttons like this, which glow when clicked, have the icon neatly arranged there, and have the little rounded corners. Using drawableLeft doesn't work because the icons get too big.

I'm guessing that there's a way to put this into a style sheet, because Google seems to do it quite consistently across their other apps.

Comment: Read up on [shape drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape). You can create a filled rounded rectangle with padding purely in XML and use that as your button background.

Comment: I'm hoping Google has their button open sourced somewhere, as the XML adjustments take quite a long time.

Comment: The default Material button shape is [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml). The referenced dimensions are defined [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml). Note, there is no `android:tint` attribute prior to API 21, so you'll need to change `@color/white` to an actual color.

Answer (score 9):

Button without icon

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/sign_up"
android:background="@drawable/action_button"
android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:id="@+id/fl_btn_signup" />
```

In Drawable you can use this `action_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />

            <solid android:color="#689F38" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />

            <solid android:color="#80689F38" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

If you want to use icons with this buttons then use `android:drawableLeft` in your Button xml or you can take a `LinearLayout` with Horizontal orientation  & with `ImageView` & `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/action_button"> //Same xml

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_apps_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="APPS"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The `LinearLayout` with the ImageView and TextView doesn't seem to click like a button though. But the button without icon works great with a little padding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of button, you can consider to use LinearLayout contains icon and text. 
Then you can apply round corner drawable resource as background for this layout (each state has its own round drawable).

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/round_states"> 

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/icon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

You can use difference round states when pressed, focus (each state has difference color)

**round_states.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/round_bg_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
   <item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/round_bg_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_bg" /> <!-- default -->
  </selector>
```

**round_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**round_bg_focused.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B8B8FF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**P/s**: There are some libraries support ripple effect when press on view on pre lollipop that you may want to try: 
https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect 
https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

Comment: A `Button` with `drawableLeft` set will give the same result, right?

Comment: @Vikram It isn't easy for you to change the distance between icon and text inside button like photo above if you use drawableLeft because there is only one property `drawablePadding`. By using LinearLayout, you can change the background state for it, and difference icon states for image in layout

Answer (score 0):

Get 9 patch images designed, with round corners (green or blue colored), for each of the buttons. Use this as a background drawable for the buttons, and provide the width and height accordingly for each button. This should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks. This might work for the MORE button example. But when using a drawable in the button, the icons don't look as clean as in the Google Play app. Any ideas for wrapping the icons into the button?

Comment: Go for creating different views and include them as different layouts. In this layout you can set the background with 9 patch images as background drawable. This entire layout can be tappable and may serve as a button for you. In a layout you can also use the different other views to include drawables for example the white android icon, etc. And also this layout shall include a textview to hold the text.

Answer (score -1):

There is one library called **[FButton](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button)** It is a custom Button of Android with `Flat UI` concept.

[image]

One more library called **[FlatUI](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI)**

[image]

also we can do the same by custom resources like this [gist!!](https://gist.github.com/dmytrodanylyk/3513e42839ae4309d2b5) by [Dmytro](http://dmytrodanylyk.com/pages/blog/flat-button.html)

Update:
For Material Design flat Button there is tons of custom libraries available

Try with **[MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)** 
[image]

Credits:Emrullah Lüleci,Le Van Hoang,Dmytro Danylyk

Comment: Thanks but I don't mean Flat UI. I mean "flat buttons" in the Material Design sense. Unfortunately they use the same name to talk about different things: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons

Comment: Update the answer ! also try to reverse engineer this code https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/PaperBoard